# Unable to execute "DESCRIBE ARADMIN.EPM_TechnicianInformation" in python jupyter notebook with cxOracle

Tags: python, sql, jupyter-notebook, cx-oracle, ora-00900

When I execute query "DESCRIBE ARADMIN.EPM_TechnicianInformation" like below:

```
connection = cx_Oracle.connect(user=username, password=userpwd, dsn=dsn, encoding="UTF-8")
cursor = connection.cursor()
results = cursor.execute(" DESCRIBE ARADMIN.EPM_TechnicianInformation")
```

It is giving

```
DatabaseError: ORA-00900: invalid SQL statement
```

How can I create query "DESCRIBE ARADMIN.EPM_TechnicianInformation" with cx_Oracle?
I want to get column details of the table.

Please help! Thanks!

Comment: did you try adding ';' at the end of the statement?

Comment: @Carlo Yes, still not working

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The '*desc*' command is a SQL*Plus command, not something the database or cx_Oracle understands.

Please check the documentation on cursor [description](https://cx-oracle.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api_manual/cursor.html?highlight=cursor%20description#Cursor.description) property of cx_Oracle.

You can try the following:

```
# sql for column details
sql = "SELECT * from ARADMIN.EPM_TechnicianInformation"
cursor.execute(sql)
print(cursor.description)
# This will print out the column description as a list, with each item referring to each column.
```

Answer (score 0):

reading from [How to execute a SQL script with cx_oracle](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57876133/how-to-execute-a-sql-script-with-cx-oracle) it looks like SQL Plus specific statements are not  understood by cx_Oracle

you can try getting the information you need by doing :

```
SELECT * FROM ALL_TABLES WHERE OWNER= 'ARADMIN' AND TABLE_NAME = 'EPM_TechnicianInformation'
```

This will give you infos on the table as well

Comment: I am getting the below error when using this - DatabaseError                             Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-34-cd31fc4b397d> in <module>
----> 1 results = cursor.execute("SELECT * FROM ALL_TABLES WHERE SCHEMA = 'ARADMIN' AND TABLE_NAME = 'EPM_TechnicianInformation'").fetchall()
DatabaseError: ORA-00904: "SCHEMA": invalid identifier

Comment: @Bharti EDITED, it's OWNER not SCHEMA, sorry for the error

Comment: @Bharti  Look for oracle dcocumentation when querying these objects ( ALL_TABLES, ALL_VIEWS, etc) you will find informations easily and they are very useful