# How to generate html report of oracle sql statement using cx_Oracle module in python?

Tags: python-3.x, oracle, cx-oracle

I have below python script dbreport.py where I am using cx_Oracle module to connect the oracle db and it is working fine.Now I have some sql statements which I want to run and generate the output of that into html report.Mentioning some part of the python script.The issue here is I want to add the below sql to generate the output in html format in below python script function.I am not sure how to achieve this.

######Sql statement to generate html report#######

```
SET MARKUP HTML ON SPOOL ON PREFORMAT OFF ENTMAP ON -
HEAD "<TITLE>EMPLOYEE REPORT</TITLE> -
<STYLE type='text/css'> -
<!-- BODY {background: #FFFFC6} --> -
</STYLE>" -
BODY "TEXT='#FF00Ff'" -
TABLE "WIDTH='90%' BORDER='5'"
spool report2.html
Select * from hr.departments where date = '{}'.format(dt_string)
spool off
```

#######dbreport.py script##########################

```
import cx_Oracle

def main(env_name):
    try:
       now datetime.now()
       dt_string = now.strftime("%Y%m%d")
       connection = Connection("ABC_DEV_KK","username", "pass")
       cursor = connection.cursor()
       cursor.execute()---------------------I tried here but not succesfull
       res = cursor.fetchall()
       print(res)
    except Exception as e:
       logging.info(e)


if _name_ == '_main_':
    main()
```

Comment: have you checked this post ? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57876133/how-to-execute-a-sql-script-with-cx-oracle

Comment: @RobertoHernandez I tried but not getting any success.

Comment: I don't think even running each command as a cursor.execute will work here.Any yea how can do this?